# Sony SmartWatch2 SW2 - Can I get all touch points?

Tags: sony, sony-smartwatch

I have a SmartWatch MN2. I understand that OnTouch is called every time there is a touch event (TOUCH_ACTION_PRESS, TOUCH_ACTION_LONGPRESS, or TOUCH_ACTION_RELEASE). I can get only the start point coordinates (PRESS) and the end point coordinates (RELEASE) when I touch the screen. But There might be many touch points between the start and end points. If I used SmartWatch2 SW2, can I find all those touch points in between?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is currently no way to do that unfortunately.  The watch does support swipe events so perhaps you could use that instead, depending on what you are trying to accomplish obviously.